# RadioButtonFor saving Null in DB [ASP.NET MVC 4]

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, radio-button, html.dropdownlistfor

i'm using the ASP.NET mvc 4 template to create my application.

I created a `UserType` as a string in UserProfile field and do a migration to update the database. It's right.

My problem is, when I'll register a new user in Register view, the application save all fields, but the UserType, it saves null, how can i resolve it? I read some topics with similar questions, but i don't know how will work to me. My code below:

With the help of @StephenMuecke ,I'm here posting the code updated, the problem is not fixed yet:

```
//Models
[Table("UserProfile")]
        public class UserProfile
        {
            [Key]
            [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
            public int UserId { get; set; }
            public string UserName { get; set; }
            public string UserType { get; set; } //flag de tipo usuário musico ou ouvinte


        }

public class RegisterModel
    {

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "User name")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Tipo de Usuario")]
        public string UserType { get; set; }


    }

//Controller
        // GET: /Account/Register

        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Register()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/Register

        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // Attempt to register the user
                try
                {
                    var user = new UserProfile() { UserName = model.UserName, UserType = model.UserType };

                    WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password);
                    WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

                }
                catch (MembershipCreateUserException e)

                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(e.StatusCode));
                }
            }

//View
@model TestTcc2.Models.RegisterModel
 <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="icode" class="col-md-3 control-label">Tipo de usuário</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            @*Html.DropDownListFor(m=> m.UserType, userTypes)*@
                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.UserType, "Ouvinte", new { id = "Ouvinte" })
                            @Html.Label("Ouvinte")
                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m=>m.UserType, "Musico", new { id= "Musico" })
                            @Html.Label("Musico")
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

EDIT:

To fix the problem with the radiobutton, i need to update the Post Register method calling the UserProfile class.

This is the code: http://pastebin.com/Mwd4QD6U

And now I'm create a new topic to ask about the exception error that i'm getting during the register
Topic link: [MemberShipException during the User Register at ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26291282/membershipexception-during-the-user-register-at-asp-net)

Comment: Are the possible values for `UserType` "Ouvinte" and "Musico"?

Comment: The values are defined in RadioButtonFor, that are: Ouvinte and Musico . @StephenMuecke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.UserType, "Ouvinte", new { id = "Ouvinte" })
@Html.Label("Ouvinte")
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m=>m.UserType, "Musico", new { id= "Musico" })
@Html.Label("Musico")
```

Comment: It's not work... Maybe, you know if i have to do some update on my controller class?

Comment: Just tested in my project and it works fine. What is you POST method signature?

Comment: This is my post and get method in AccountController class
http://pastebin.com/KNn8GPkG 
I'm afraid that the radiobutton is not working fine, it's can happen?

Comment: Your model is `UserProfile` but your posting back to `public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)`? Either the model in the view should be `RegisterModel` or the method signature should be `public ActionResult Register(UserProfile model)`

Comment: Sorry by my delay. In my view `Register`, i'm using the model `RegisterModel`, and if i change to `UserProfile` in this view, the   `password` field shows a error, because in the UserProfile, don't have the field password, understand? This is my RegisterModel http://pastebin.com/Qrmy6xEZ

Comment: If your view uses `@model RegisterModel` then my answer will work fine. Note you should edit you answer with the full view code and controller method - not add links. And why did you include the code for `public class UserProfile` if its not being used?

Comment: But, if i put the `ActionResult Register(UserProfile model)`, my view will not work, because the UserProfile class don't have the password field :(

Comment: No, leave the controller as is. If your view uses `@model RegisterModel` then you controller should be `public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)`. but looking at you first link, you don't even use the property `UserType` anyway, so whats it for?

Comment: Ok, i understood your point. I have the `UserType` in both classes (`UserProfile and RegisterModel`), the `userType value must be saved in UserProfile`. `RegisterModel` is not a table on my DB, `UserProfile` is. The values of radiobutton must be saved in UserProfile, i think that the new point of this doubt is, how can i reference the `RegisterModel.UserType` in `UserProfile.UserType` to save the value of radiobutton in `UserProfile`, understand it? Correct me if i wrong...

Comment: If you inspect the value of `model` in your controller POST method, you will see that it is either `Ouvinte` or `Musico` so just get its value and do what you need (create a new instance of `UserProfile`, set its property `UserType` to `model.UserType` and save it or whatever) - you have not posted enough information to know exactly what your doing

Comment: Every new user that will register on application, must be `Ouvinte` or `Musica`, this attribute will work like UserRoles to application. I'll try to update my POST method, to reference the `UserProfile` to save the attribute `UserType` in  `ÙserProfile` table. It's more clear for you about what i'm trying to do? If you want, could add me in skype `pedrro.1`

Comment: Hey @StephenMuecke now I'm saving the userType in DB, thank you for your help! But, I'm entering in exception on line 17, maybe, can you look and try to help-me, this is the new code that i do on register http://pastebin.com/Mwd4QD6U The exceptions says that the name is already exists.

Comment: @PedroHenrique, That's a completely different issue to you original question and you need to ask a **new** question (that's the rules of SO). If the value of `model.UserType` is no longer null, then this question has now been resolved.

Comment: Okay, I'll open a new question and post the resolution here. But tomorrow i do this. Thank you for all support provide to me Stephen, you're really good! And sorry for something :p

Comment: This is the link to the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26291282/membershipexception-during-the-user-register-at-asp-net Thank you!